# Convert points inserted to line and stored in a column in sql server in a trigeer

Tags: sql-server

I'm basically making a script convert points inserted to line and stored in a column in sql server in a trigeer but I don't find it.
I tried:

```
DECLARE @BuildString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @BuildString = COALESCE(@BuildString + ',', '') + CAST([Lng] AS NVARCHAR(50)) + ' ' + CAST([Lat] AS NVARCHAR(50))
FROM dbo.ligneTemp


SET @BuildString = 'LINESTRING(' + @BuildString + ')';   
DECLARE @LineFromPoints geometry =geometry::STLineFromText(@BuildString, 4326);
SELECT @LineFromPoints
END
```